# Will foam tape stop condensation on metal windows?

Tags: insulation, windows, condensation

I am having an issue that water is building up on the inside of my metal window. has anyone tried putting foam tape on inside or outside to stop condensation?

Comment: How old are the windows? Sounds like they need restoration, not foam tape.

Comment: Hi, did you ever try this?  Anyone have any experience of this?  I might try it...

Answer (score 1):

What you really need is a dehumidifier, foam insulation on the inside will help but the window will probably still sweat as long as your humidity is high with cold weather. whatever you do don't block the outside weep drains at the bottom of your windows or the tracks may fill with water and possibly freeze solid on really cold days. They make plug in dehumidifiers that are not two expensive , other than that make sure when bathing that the exhaust fan is on, when cooking make sure the exhaust fan is on both help remove the moisture,,, [here is a link to a small portable unit](http://www.target.com/p/eva-dry-electric-petite-dehumidifier-white/-/A-12934689?ci_src=17588969&ci_sku=12934689&ref=tgt_adv_XS000000&AFID=google_pla_df&CPNG=PLA_Health%2BBeauty_Priority%2BShopping&adgroup=Health%2BBeauty_Priority%20TCINs&LID=700000001170770pgs&network=g&device=c&location=1024453&gclid=CM_btNzjpskCFYVrfgod0OUEjQ&gclsrc=aw.ds) so you can see what I am talking about.

Comment: I edited your message to clean up some spelling and clean up that hugely messy link. If you must use links the preferred way to handle them is like I show in my edit.

Comment: I have figured out how to put in links since then thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say no & also give it a shot. But, not a thin tape. Go, for sticky backed weather-stripping that's at least 1/4" deep & wide enough to cover or slightly over-cover the frame (2-strips side by side if needed). If you do outside too then paint it to protect it from UV exposure & like Ed Beal said, don't block the weep-holes...you'll get a lot more "sweat" if you do that.

Otherwise, get storm windows to make a dead-air insulating space. Good news bad news...these will save you from getting new windows, but they cost about the same as new windows if you can imagine that absurdity.